# getting wrong value for div height using jquery

Tags: jquery, height

I've this simple html page with a div called container set to min-height 1800px after adding more content to the page and using the jquery to get the real height i get a wrong value. the real height now is 1907 (from inspect element) and jquery alerts 1887 using this code

```
var container_h = $(".container").height();
alert(container_h);
```

I've changed height to innerHeight but didn't work too here's the page http://www.mawk3y.net/alsoos/hathal/

Comment: It returns 1907 in the console, so you're too fast, the container hasn't gotten it's full height yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

When setting outerHeight(true) you include the margins. Otherwise it returns height + padding.

```
var container_h = $(".container").outerHeight(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling your code after the DOM is ready. If you're not, the elements won't be "initialized".

```
$(function() { *your code here* });
```

Answer (score -1):

used setTimeout (inside document ready for sure) to late the new function that gets the height of the container

```
setTimeout(getHeight,500);

function getHeight(){
var container_h = $(".container").outerHeight();
```

}

Comment: I know you're new to javascript so I'll be gentle: This solution is wrong. You should never, ever use setTimeout to wait for ui to render. You should use callbacks instead.